# How to use parent, before, children etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="123"></td><td><input class="here" type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="333"></td><td><input class="here" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>

$(".here").click(function(){

     alert($(this).parent().before().children().val());

})
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4enGp/

If i click on input with class **here** then this should show me value from first input in this TR, but this show me value from current input. How can i make it?

Comment: You probably mean `.prev()` whey you say `.before()`.

Comment: @lanzz please add new answer :)

Comment: Esailija's answer actually beat my comment by a few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this).parent().prev().find("input").val()`

http://jsfiddle.net/4enGp/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(".here").click(function(){
   jQuery(this).parent("td").prev("td").find("input").val();
})​;
```